# Did Republicans mock Biden for showing grief over the loss of his dog?

Tags: united-states, dogs, joe-biden

In June, [George Takei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Takei) [tweeted](https://twitter.com/georgetakei/status/1406351997452828673):

> Republicans are mocking Biden for showing grief over the loss of his dog.
>
> If you lose your dog but feel nothing, you might be a Republican.

As of today, this tweet has 14K retweets and 100K likes. Did Republicans mock Biden for showing grief over the loss of his dog? Are there any prominent examples?

Answer (score 49):

I'm not sure what level of Google-exhaustion one needs to show before drawing a negative conclusion on an existence question like this, but it's probably quite safe to conclude that there are no prominent Republicans who have done this, or there would be a media furore, by analogy with the one that did happen further back in the spring when Newsmax aired a weird segment about the same dog--something about the dog not being presidential enough in their view. (And I mean there was even coverage in the foreign press, at least in the [French](https://www.lepoint.fr/monde/le-chien-de-joe-biden-juge-indigne-d-un-president-des-etats-unis-21-02-2021-2414871_24.php) and [Spanish](https://www.lavanguardia.com/television/20210222/6257745/presentador-critica-burla-joe-biden-aspecto-perro-bano.html) press about that incident.)

There is one fairly obscure [website](https://www.politicalflare.com/2021/06/trump-supporters-mock-the-bidens-for-mourning-the-passing-of-their-dog-champ/) that makes a similar claim to the Tweet in question, but the only examples it gives are at best some mockery of the level of news coverage that the dog's death had, and some rather odd numerology stuff. Similarly with the latter, there's some [QAnon talk](https://www.newsweek.com/qanon-believers-suggest-secret-message-behind-announcement-biden-dogs-death-1602280) of a secret message or some such behind the death of Biden's dog. None of those seem to meet the exact claim that Biden's grief reaction was mocked.

---

It turns out that's not the whole story surrounding the reactions to the dog's death. There was some press coverage ([even](https://www.berlingske.dk/usa/bidens-hund-champ-er-doed-mens-major-fortsat-lever-videre-det-er-biden) international) of an article (and related tweet) by National Review columnist Dan McLaughlin. [Laurel's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/52326/) has more details on this.

Comment: Any guess on Takei's source? In my own Google searching I found only one other source claiming this (a bit of an obscure one), but the given examples were nobodies on Twitter and none mocking Biden's grief.

Comment: I recall seeing some mocking of the *media coverage* of the death, perhaps that was being misconstrued as mockery of his grief.

Comment: @fredsbend Given Takei's long history of Twitter trolling, it's quite possible that his "source" is "made it up because it sounds plausible and is a good topic to stir up outrage from."

Comment: Perhaps there is conflation between two events, as Newsmax reportedly mocked Biden's dog, Champ, while he was still alive a few months prior to his death.

Answer (score 19):

I found Twitter to be pretty civil in its response to the death of Biden’s dog, within the narrow timeframe between it being announced and that tweet. I found more examples of people claiming Republicans were mocking Biden about this than I did Republicans (or people one could assume are Republican) doing anything that could be construed as mocking Biden or the dog's death or similar.

---

On [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=(dog%20OR%20champ)%20biden%20min_faves%3A1000%20until%3A2021-06-20%20since%3A2021-06-18&src=typed_query&f=top), you can search `(dog OR champ) biden min_faves:1000 since:2021-06-18 until:2021-06-20` to get many Tweets talking about the event around the time that Takei tweeted. I scanned through the "top" results, and found this:

- 19 consoling or neutral/factual Tweets
- 1 [joke Tweet](https://twitter.com/LiZaOutlives/status/1406280284824387586). It does not seem politically motivated as the account mainly jokes about death.
- A [Tweet mocking Rush Limbaugh](https://twitter.com/BMeiselas/status/1406281639232032773) (but not the dog), quoting a screenshot of a deleted Tweet from an account that I can't quite identify politically except as anti-MAGA.
- [Another joke](https://twitter.com/ByYourLogic/status/1406279527685312513). I don't think this one is mocking the death of the dog, but I would certainly interpret some of the responses to it as doing so (though none have many likes)
- A [joke about a drawing](https://twitter.com/ecareyo/status/1406310003732979712) of who the dog would meet in heaven (doesn't seem to be hostile to me though)
- I saw Takei's Tweet in this search, and I saw another ([27.5k likes](https://twitter.com/OhNoSheTwitnt/status/1406299863395012612)) talking about the same thing, and another that may hint at this

Other than these, one message stood out to me, the [Tweet written by National Review writer Dan McLaughlin](https://twitter.com/baseballcrank/status/1406275853084921861) (@baseballcrank):

> Champ Biden dies, Major lives on. The Biden family tragedy in miniature.

The reactions to this Tweet make it clear that many people saw this as blatantly offensive, a dismissive, mocking response. For example, "[You are a truly awful person](https://twitter.com/TVietor08/status/1406297320161890304?s=20)" and "[This is beyond horrid. Delete this & apologize.](https://twitter.com/OliviaTroye/status/1406302636761038850?s=20)" Many people left even stronger negative reactions to the Tweet. A link to this Tweet can be found in the replies to Takei's. It seems to me like this may be what Takei was referring to in his tweet.

You can find other popular Tweets mocking the death of the dog ([example from a political "satire" account](https://twitter.com/walterowensgrpa/status/1406293321484484611)), though they do not have as many likes nor have they been from notable people.

---

When I looked at news articles via Google News using a similar search, I found even less of note. There were a handful of articles that were consoling or neutral about the dog's death, and really only one noteworthy article beyond that: [McLaughlin's National Review article](https://www.nationalreview.com/corner/the-shakespearean-father-son-tragedy-of-the-biden-family). It mentions the dog dying in passing (not mocking that), then goes on to criticize the Biden family for unrelated things (comes off as a bizarre and perhaps inappropriate transition from the beginning of the article). However, we can say definitively this is not what Takei was talking about, as it was published after the tweet.